# SlickGrid constructor issue with Columns parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, slickgrid

I have a very simple SlickGrid example loaded into a solution.  To do this, I first ran *npm install slickgrid*, and then incorporated a very basic slickgrid example, which is as follows:

The Typescript file contains the imports and code to initialize the grid:

```
import { SlickGrid } from 'slickgrid/*';
```

.
.
.

```
var data = [
    { id: 1, title: 'Task 1', duration: '5', percentComplete: 20, start: '1/1/2022', finish: '1/5/2022', effortDriven: false },
    { id: 2, title: 'Task 2', duration: '10', percentComplete: 40, start: '1/6/2022', finish: '1/15/2022', effortDriven: false },
    { id: 3, title: 'Task 3', duration: '15', percentComplete: 60, start: '1/16/2022', finish: '1/30/2022', effortDriven: false },
    { id: 4, title: 'Task 4', duration: '20', percentComplete: 80, start: '2/1/2022', finish: '2/20/2022', effortDriven: false },
    { id: 5, title: 'Task 5', duration: '25', percentComplete: 100, start: '2/21/2022', finish: '3/15/2022', effortDriven: false }
];

var columns = [
    { id: 'id', name: 'ID', field: 'id' },
    { id: 'title', name: 'Title', field: 'title' },
    { id: 'duration', name: 'Duration', field: 'duration' },
    { id: '%', name: '% Complete', field: 'percentComplete' },
    { id: 'start', name: 'Start', field: 'start' },
    { id: 'finish', name: 'Finish', field: 'finish' },
    { id: 'effort-driven', name: 'Effort Driven', field: 'effortDriven' }
];

var options = {
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    enableColumnReorder: false
};

var grid = new SlickGrid('#myGrid', data, columns, options);
```

However, this generates a compiler error.  The *columns* array seems to be expecting the same data type as *data*.  Navigating to the *SlickGrid* constructor, this seems to make sense, givent the *SlickGrid* constructor and class export definition:

```
constructor(protected container: HTMLElement | string, protected data: CustomDataView<TData> | TData[], protected columns: C[], protected options: Partial<O>)

export class SlickGrid<TData = any, C extends Column<TData> = Column<TData>, O extends BaseGridOption<C> = BaseGridOption<C>>
```

[image]

I have very little UI/UX experience in general, and none with SlickGrid, so I'm sure I've got something set up incorrectly, or I'm using the wrong class/namespace, or something, but I'm not sure how else to diagnose/fix.  Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import is incorrect, I don't know why VSCode sometime automatically adds the `/*` but it should really be `from 'slickgrid';` (without ending `/*`). You should read the v5.0 migration guide, there's more info and usage example there, see [Annoucement Migration 5.0](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Major-version-5.0-%E2%80%90-ES6-ESM-and-TypeScript-Support)

Also it looks like you're using TypeScript since you're getting a TypeScript error, so you should also add the `Column` type to your columns

```
import { Column, SlickGrid } from 'slickgrid';

let columns: Column[] = [
  // ...
];
```

Your issue is kind similar to this SlickGrid [issue](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/issues/848) but you're not using dynamic `field`, so I'm not sure why it would show this error apart from the fact that you should add the `Column` type like I said (which is probably your problem here). I'm not entirely sure since I don't know if you've put this inside a `.ts` file or if you're using `<script type="module">`

The `field` type has a TS helper on it and it's supposed to provide more help but you're the second person encountering a problem with it, if it's too much hassle, I might revert to a simple `field: string` instead. The field helper when it works will help you a lot with the intellisense since it will show you the field of available field when you provide an interface to SlickGrid

[image]

Comment: Both of those Column recommendations fixed the issue, thanks so much for the quick response.  I did have things in a .ts file.  Will look through the migration docs as well for usage guidelines.  Thanks again.

Comment: ok great, thanks for reporting back and glad that fixed it so I won't have to revert `field` to a simple `string` type :)

Comment: added a note in the migration about these 2 issues, thanks again for confirming